# What is wrong with my select sort algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I tried to perform the selection algorithm, but it has not turned out how I expected and what I have been studying, what am I failing?

I need an answer explained, I do not come to do tasks of my class, I come to learn.

```js
function selectSort(arr) {
 var length = arr.length, // Array length
     temp = 0, // Temporal var
     min = 0; // Minimum
     
     for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) { // Iterate over the array
         for(var k = i; k < length; k++) { // Iterate to find the minimun element
             var cur = arr[k]; // Current element
             if(cur < min) min = k; // If the current element is less than the min, change the new min value
         } 
         temp = arr[i]; // Save temporarily the current variable
         arr[i] = arr[min]; 
         arr[min] = temp;
         // Change values
         temp = null; // Delete reference
     }
     return arr;
}

console.log(selectSort([3,49,10,3,2,17,4,6,9,1]))
```

Comment: your algorithm is wrong: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: If you need to sort the array you can try to use the `sort()` built-in method: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: @MitchWheat It's obvious, I say it in my question

Comment: @Adriano I never asked for that in my question

Comment: It's obvious that you aren't able to translate pseudo code? Not sure how you expect help with that. Read the wiki and notice where this line : var cur = arr[k]; // Current element should be, and you have mixed min index with value

Comment: You need to describe the algorithm you're trying to implement and the desired output. Just showing non–working code leads to confusion over what you're trying to implement (simple bubble sort?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In condition you should write cur < a[min]

2) Min must be initialized on every iteration, min = i

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in your code whether `min` is supposed to be the *index* of the minimum value (in the searched region) or the minimum *value* itself. You're using it in both ways, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're comparing the current value to the index of the minimum value instead of the current minimum value.

This should work:

```js
function selectSort(arr) {
 var length = arr.length, // Array length
     temp = 0, // Temporal var
     min = 0; // Minimum
     
     for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) { // Iterate over the array
         for(var k = i; k < length; k++) { // Iterate to find the minimun element
             var cur = arr[k]; // Current element
             if(arr[k] < arr[min]) min = k; // If the current element is less than the min, change the new min value
         } 
         temp = arr[i]; // Save temporarily the current variable
         arr[i] = arr[min]; 
         arr[min] = temp;
         // Change values
         temp = null; // Delete reference
     }
     return arr;
}

console.log(selectSort([3,49,10,3,2,17,4,6,9,1]))
```

Comment: "[*Temporal*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/temporal)" should be "*Temporary*". ;-)